# ProgressBar Paint Method?

Tags: c#, progress-bar, visual-c#-express-2010

OK, here is my code for what to paint on the progressbar:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int percent = progressBar1.Value;
        progressBar1.CreateGraphics().DrawString(percent.ToString() + "%", new Font("Arial", (float)8.25, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new PointF(progressBar1.Width / 2 - 10, progressBar1.Height / 2 - 7));
        progressBar1.Increment(+1);
        if (progressBar1.Value >= 99)
        {
            timer2.Stop();
            this.Close();
        }
```

Ok, so i am painting a label in the middle of it that will display the progressbar's value. For some reason, it keeps blinking....disappearing and reappearing. So, someone told me to take out that code and put it in the paint method.....i do not see it. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Check if setting `DoubleBuffered` to true makes any difference.

Comment: where is DoubleBuffered? Is it in the progressbar...or what? I am new, so...sorry

Comment: @EliteGamer It is a property of the form itself.

Comment: Also, why is my form closing so early...it gets to about 97 then stops

Comment: I think it is more logical to draw something in the paint method, than doing it from somewhere else. Performance wise I don't know if there's any different. DoubleBuffered can be of great help.

Comment: Never use this method to draw on the controls. Every time the control redraw him self(invalidate), he will override your drawing which gives that flickering effect (you draw, he invalidate and erase and so on...). This has nothing to do with Double Buffering which also causes flickering effect but is more due to the lack of fps

Comment: Check the code I uploaded, it should work as you expect it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a code that should work (I went with option number 3, creating a child Class and overriding the WndProc to handle the paint message:

```
public class Prog : ProgressBar
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == 0x000F)
        {
            var flags = TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter |
                        TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter |
                        TextFormatFlags.SingleLine |
                        TextFormatFlags.WordEllipsis;

            TextRenderer.DrawText(CreateGraphics(),
                                  ((float)this.Value/this.Maximum*100) + "%",
                                  Font,
                                  new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height),
                                  Color.Black,
                                  flags);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Elite Gamer: Create an event handler for the control's Paint event. In the event handler body, use the Graphics object from PaintEventArgs parameter to do your drawing. Note that the Paint event may be raised many times, even between two ticks of your timer.

Comment: I do not see the paint thing for the progressbar?

Comment: After verification it seems option 2 is not possible for the particular case of a progress bar. The Paint event is hidden. I would go with option 1.

Comment: check this for option 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517179/c-overriding-onpaint-on-progressbar-not-working

Comment: but on number 1, the label will not be transparent...am i not correct?

Comment: @lcfseth Edited to make code more readable and elegant (with no annoying scroll bar) and fixed typo "pain message" to "paint message"

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [ProgressBarRenderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbarrenderer.aspx) to do the whole drawing by yourself.