# How to have a transparent number on top of a winform?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

So I have a winform that has some winforms controls on it. But in the center of it, I want to show a transparent number on top of everything. Say 60 pixels size.

I tried a label and even tried to create a custom control but the transparency didn't work.

Any ideas how to do this?

This number will change programmatically at runtime several times.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605920/reasons-for-why-a-winforms-label-does-not-want-to-be-transparent might be of some help.

Comment: Is the number transparent, or is the background around the number transparent?

Comment: @Stewbob, both are transparent, but I would like it more if the background around the number is completely invisible. So no background, and the number is semi transparent.