# Win Xp, transparent label on winform gradient background not working

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency

For my application im making "Toast" like alerts. Im using an override method on the forms "Paint" event to create a custom gradient. The form then has a picture box, and 3 labels on it, all with transparent backgrounds. On XP, the background of these controls are being set to the form's original background color, and the images / text not being displayed.

On windows 7:

[image: Windows 7 Display]

On Windows XP:

[image: Windows XP Display]

My Paint method:

```
    private void AlertForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(
            this.ClientRectangle,
            Color.Black,
            Color.DimGray,
            120F))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any advice to fix the issues on windows XP please?

**UPDATE**: Here is the source code to my form, minus design code: http://pastebin.com/RUYtM7qu

**FIXED:** I have found the issue to be due to the animation of the form. If i just show the form, it displays fine, but as soon as i move it, the text and icon disapear. I decided to register for the "LocationChanged" event, and manually call this.Refresh()" on the form, and that fixed the problem!

Comment: If you remove the `FillRectangle` call does it show ok on XP?

Comment: No it does not. The backgrounds are still filled with black

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/605944/44853 and the answer it links to

Comment: I don't think this is an issue of XP, I used XP before and it rendered many third party controls (such as from DevExpress which supports many skinny controls in winforms) OK.

Comment: Using the transparent label as posted by LC works... but the foreground text is still missing

Comment: This code works fine on XP. I've created a new project, added a pictureBox, 3 labels, used the above code, set an image for the pictureBox, set the backColor of the labels to Transparent and the form's opacity to 70%.

Comment: Well, my form is using a timer as well, that is sliding the form up every 20 milliseconds until the form is displayed just above the taskbar. Here is the complete source to my form (minus designer stuff) http://pastebin.com/RUYtM7qu