# Removing Padding Around Custom CircularProgressBar Control

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, custom-controls

I think I may have been going about this wrong. As I stated in another thread, I thought the issue was with the transparency of the controls overlapping. I guess it still could be, but, now I'm wondering if there is a way to remove the clear border around the custom drawn control? I have been trying to figure it out, and have yet to find anything on StackOverflow or Google about it. I want the line of the circularprogressbar behind the other to touch the line of circularprogressbar in front.

Here is an image of what it looks like right now. I have both selected to show the border I am referring to. Is there a way to remove that border? Would this solve the problem I am facing?

[image: CircularProgressBars w/ Border]

Here is the link to my original thread about the transparency. I have been racking my brains out with this control.

[Transparent Overlapping Circular Progress Bars (Custom Control)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365918/transparent-overlapping-circular-progress-bars-custom-control)

I have removed padding from the control properties (0, 0, 0, 0) and removed margin (0, 0, 0, 0). These options had no effect on the control.

Thanks for any help! :)

**UPDATE 1:** As requested, here is a picture of what I am trying to achieve. I want to reveal more of that back circularprogress bar, so that the two touch. Basically, removing the outside the border/padding between the rectangle and circle.

[image: Update 1]

Comment: *"I want the line of the circularprogressbar behind the other to touch the line of circularprogressbar in front"* - could you visually present what you want (using Paint cut and paste how they should be) ? I see there is a gap between circle and bounding rectangle (is that a problem?), but I fail to imagine how circles should touch each other.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated the post above to show what I am trying to achieve visually.

Comment: Don't use a control.  Just paint what you want on the visible canvas by passing the graphic object from the paint event to your "progress class".