# Paint Event e.Graphics.DrawImage doesn't seem to follow double buffering

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-5

Currently working on a rewrite of older code where I'm using Graphics functions to draw an interactive vector-based map based off location data.

Back when this was using .NET 4.7, I could simply draw my stuff into a Bitmap, do Graphics gr = Panel.CreateGraphics(), then gr.DrawImage(). I never enabled double buffering, and it always worked fine.

Now I'm in .NET 5, still with WinForms, and trying to do things a bit better based off a Paint event and invalidating the component whenever it's interacted with.

This is the core of my problem here

```
Bitmap Buffer; //this is initialized elsewhere, don't worry

public void MapPlotPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
//... Drawing code removed, it's just a novel Graphics object drawing into the Bitmap ...
e.Graphics.DrawImage(Buffer, Point.Empty);
}
```

While this draws the image into the panel fine, I get terrible flickering, as I can see the bitmap being drawn into the panel in real time. Even if I Panel.CreateGraphics() inside the event handler and use that instead of the PaintEventArgs object, exactly as I did previously, the same thing happens.

Within a Form load event handler, I have

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
```

Which has no effect.

The darnedest thing, though, is if instead of applying the image the panel using Graphics, I do Panel.BackgroundImage = Buffer, it'll never flicker, but then of course, what's drawn only shows the next time the component is invalidated.

I seriously can't think what I might be missing here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `Control.CreateGraphics()` anywhere in your code. Then, use a double-buffered Control as a PictureBox or a flat Label. Not clear why you have this: `MapPlotGraphics.DrawImage(Buffer, Point.Empty);` in the Paint event of a Control. Shouldn't you draw the Image onto the Control's DC? What is this method? Why don't you have `e.Graphics.DrawImage(Buffer, ...)` there? -- Remove all those `SetStyle()` stuff from the Form's constructor (`Load` event?).

Comment: Ah, my bad, that was an experiment I forgot to change back.. I am /not/ using Control.CreateGraphics() anywhere in my code, I used to, now I am reimplenting it. I can try a PictureBox real quick, I've been using a Panel, so maybe that's for some reason the problem.

Comment: You need to do this `SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);` for the drawing canvas not the Form. The Panel in your case. Subclass and enable that or just use a PictureBox, double-buffered by default.

Comment: Panels are not double-buffered. You use these for painting, using the `OptimizedDoubleBuffer` feature, to get some *special effects* (a *mild persistence* of the Graphics). You can see one here: [Transparent Overlapping Circular Progress Bars (Custom Control)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53379442/7444103): you won't get the same result with a Control that uses the standard BufferedGraphics. -- Post the real code. (BTW, `SetStyle()` is called from the **Constructor** of a Control, not the `Load` event)

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense, and is exactly the problem. Many thanks, if anyone wants to write a quick answer, I'll accept the first one I see. Appreciate everyone's quick help.

Comment: For drawing I recommend either PBox or (!) Label. Both are double-buffered out of the box. Label is the simpler control, PBox has Imge and BackgroundImage in addition to its surface. Panel is a container and not really good for drawing on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments - to enable Double Buffering of the panel you need to `SetStyle()` within the panel constructor, not in the form load event. To do so, you have to create your own panel. Bellow the sample code of custom panel class.

```
public partial class CustomPanel : UserControl
{
    public CustomPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Add Double Buffering
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
    }
}
```