# Two Transparent Panels drawing parallel to each other in C# Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing

I have two panels of equal length. Lets say 100x100 and I am drawing a line from (0,0) to (50,50) on both of the panels

[image]

This is the result of it. Both panels are transparent in color. Is it not possible to show the both the drawings together when two panels overlap each other?

```
panel1.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red,3),new Point(0,0), new Point(100,100));
panel2.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red,3),new Point(0,0), new Point(100,100));
```

The code is very basic.

Both panels draw a basic line via Pen.

Comment: [Transparent Overlapping Circular Progress Bars (Custom Control)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53379442/7444103) -- Panels have a slightly different behavior when made transparent than other Controls, as the PictureBox or a Label (see, e.g., [Translucent circular Control with text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51435842/7444103)). Don't use `CreateGraphics()` for this, or ever, if you need the drawing to persist