# C# Label(Transparent backGround) on PictureBox (on Panel)

Tags: c#, panel, picturebox

I want to draw the Labels on PictureBoxes but should be transparent background .
This is my code : `

```
                           Labels[i].Location = new Point(0, 0);
                            Labels[i].Size = new Size(13, 13);
                            Labels[i].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                            Labels[i].ForeColor = Color.Blue;


  Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { Panels.Controls.Add(Pictures[i]); }));
                                    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { Panels.Controls.Add(Labels[i]); }));
```

I'am drawing my Pictures fine, Labels too ... But I get the Labels under the Pictures (I can see each label when I drag the Picture out of his place)
so I want to know , how I can put them in Front with Transparent BackGround . thank you
`

Comment: Your Controls.Add() call is wrong.  You must add it to the PictureBox, not the Panel.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use something like **z-index**

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `Panels.Controls[Labels[i].Name].BringToFront();` in your delegate. This should bring each label in front of the pictures since they've already been added to the panel at that point.

Comment: It does bring them ... but won't get Transparent BackGround as should be .

Comment: I assume you are using winforms yes? In that case changing a BackColor will not work. There are work arounds but it is not possible in winforms by default, perhaps you'd be better off using WPF. Take a look at an old but relevant thread with workaround for transparency here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639482/how-to-do-a-background-for-a-label-will-be-without-color

Comment: Well I need this in WinForms

Comment: Then you'll have to research some of the work-arounds listed in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you've already googled for this but here's a [good link about winforms transparency](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25048/How-to-Use-Transparent-Images-and-Labels-in-Window).

I used to write many winforms applications that used very ugly skins with transparent labels. As I can remember there was some glitches when used jpg as a background picture and if picture loaded *after* the label has been drawn.

Anyway, I suggest overriding onPaint and onDraw methods as you can see in the link.

Comment: Yes I did .I was able to fix the problem by my own but thank you anyway guys .

Answer (score 0):

Transparency is only with respect to the container.  For this to work you have to add the Label to the **PictureBox**.  Change `Panels` to the name of the PictureBox you are working with in the `Controls.Add()` line.