# How can I make a transparent label on a panel?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I make a label transparent on all the panels I have? I couldn't find any solution for it when searching on Google, also the Transparent color won't make it transparent on all panels.

[image: The label]

Comment: Labels are transparent by default, but transparency will only work when the control is __nested__. If it instead it __overlaps__ it will not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a background for a label will be without color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639482/how-to-do-a-background-for-a-label-will-be-without-color)

Answer (score 0):

```
label.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

or you can set it to same color as the parent .

But you will probably get some problems with transparency ... since it's winform ..

Answer (score 0):

This one is **tricky** and got me **several times**. What you can do is **update the label's back color to the panel's one** like this :

```
private void UpdateBackColor()
{
  label1.BackColor = panel1.BackColor;
}
```

This will set the label color the same as your panel color, essentially solving your problem.

Comment: This and the other answer won't work, cause then the border of the panel will be hidden from view

Comment: Yeah but why would he add it on the border? It's completely useless, and the border does NOT show when launching the program.

Comment: If he doesn't want the border, then you should have labeled this question as a duplicate, because the answer already exists.

Comment: Well, I didn't know that the answer already existed, sorry. Next time I'll search more.

Comment: No need to ask sorry and I didn't mean any insult. You're new here and everybody makes mistakes. Just advising.