# Text doesn't display on transparent label

Tags: c#, winforms, transparent

I built a winform with transparent labels whit text in the labels.
In my computer it's working well, but on some of the users computer it doesn't display the text.
What I did wrong?

```
this.label.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
this.label.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
```

Comment: That works just fine.  The only real explanation is that, for some reason, the parent of the Label has a black background.  So you'd get black text on a black background, an obvious hazard of using transparency.  You'll need to work on posting a proper repro.

Answer (score 0):

See **Rune Grimstad** Answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373913/setting-the-parent-of-a-usercontrol-prevents-it-from-being-transparent/373961#373961).

WinForms doesn't support transparent well.

Otherwise try to use a LinkLabel and not a normal Label.